# Social share with twitter not working when logged out

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, twitter

On my website I have this social share for twitter

```
const url = `https://twitter.com/share?text=${encodeURIComponent('Some text to share')}.&url=https://example.com`;


window.open(url, 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=580,height=325');
```

This will show a popup

[image]

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/jeanluca/mwLc0e9h/1/)

Works like a charm, but when you are not logged in, you'll get the following dialog

[image]

Now, when I click on the `Log in and Tweet` button, the dialog updated, and I get the following

[image]

The tweet is gone. This happens on my macbook with Chrome. I tested with Safari which seems to work as expected.

Any suggestion how I can fix this with Chrome?

It seems related to the `window.open`, if you just use an anchor with `target="_blank:` it works

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue you describe. I used the result from your JSFiddle and as soon as I logged in, the tweet was posted and the pop-up window closed as expected. (Tested on Chrome 75 on Mac)

Comment: Weird, I just tried it and it did work. I will investigate this further, but maybe twitter or chrome fixed something, could be. But thanks for checken!